# In Powershell, how can I replace a string that contains a question mark?

Tags: powershell, replace

In Powershell, how can I replace a string that contains a question mark?  For example:

`(Get-Content file.txt) -replace "Hello?","Hello."`

The question mark seems to be interpreted as some kind special character.  Is there a way to escape it?  I tried using one or two backticks, but no success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses Regular Expression pattern matching. In RegEx the question mark is a quantifier indicating the previous match should be matched zero or one times. You can escape the question mark by placing a backslash before it as such:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace "Hello\?","Hello."
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I figured there was a simple solution, but I could not find it.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer resolves your question please mark it as accepted to help future searchers find it more easily. (green check mark on the left)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `.Replace()` string method and it doesn't use regex